# Please explain the reasoning behind these ACL question/answers?

Tags: cisco, acl

Is it just me that think there has to be something wrong with these questions/answers?

1) Why is this the best answer? How does the correct answer achieve the objective? The ACL says:

Deny any TCP traffic with IP addresses belonging to the 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 (match first 24 bits, left to right) with source port 80 to a single IP address 10.1.1.101

then allow all other traffic that doesn't match above

If I do that ^^^ outbound of serial 0/0/0 (sample config), it does make more sense to analyze the traffic before you send it out / before it could reach the destination.

Changing the config to "ip access-group 170 i" won't prevent packets from 172.16.0.0/16 and 192.168.1.0/24 from reaching Branch.

If it was me, I would write

```
deny ip 172.16.0.0 0.0.255.255 10.1.1.0 0.0.0.255
deny ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 10.1.1.0 0.0.0.255
permit ip any any
```

[image]

2) This question uses the same configs but has a different objective. How does this config/example achieve the desired objective? The port should have been on the destination address.

[image]

Thank you all for you time.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions for "_education, certification, or homework_" are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

**Short answer**

FWIW I also don't see how the answer marked in green would be the correct answer. In fact I don't see how any of those answers would be the correct answer.

**Long answer**

If I wanted to protect Branch I'd set incoming rules on the Branch network.

But, if only City_HQ is under my control, I can either drop what's incoming from Branch, or drop what's outgoing to Branch.

I prefer working with incoming rules. And when I start using rules I prefer using "deny any any" as last resort with explicit permits before that. But that's from a firewall perspective. We are talking about routers here... YMMV

2)

AFAICS the config is almost correct but should say

```
deny tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.1.1.101 eq 80
```

(port should be specified on destination side)

Again I don't see how any of the red or green answers (or other) would be correct.

Comment: I got this from the Cisco Learning Network. They are already looking into revising these questions. Thanks for confirming.